# IF Formula to multiply different criteria by different values

Tags: excel, formula

I need to write an IF formula so that anything less than 100 is multiplied by 7, and anything 100 and over is multiplied by 1.

I have tried the following formulas:

```
=G2*IF(G2>1,7,IF(G2>99,1))


=IF(G17=100,””,G17*7)
```

These both work for numbers less than 100, but they also multiply anything 100+ by 7.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Try `=IF(G2<100,G2*7,G2*1)`.

Comment: If you want to keep blank for hundred then try `=IF(G2=100,"",IF(G2<100,G2*7,G2*1))`.

Comment: @Jaynee: by the way, your first formula won't work because any number greater than 100 is also greater than 1. Therefore the IF function will always return 7 for any number greater than 1 or 100. Your second formula won't work because: if G17 is equal to 100 it will return an empty string; otherwise it will multiply G17 by 7, no matter if it's greater or less than either 100 or 1.

Comment: So I tried the formula =IF(G2<100,G2*7,G2*1) and it works for the value over 100, but is also multiplying the values less than 100 by 1.  Could it be because in column G I have the  formula =TEXTBEFORE(F2, {"weeks"," days"}) ,so the IF formula can't recognise the value?

Comment: Yes, TEXTBEFORE returns text. Convert it to number by multiplying by 1 before comparing: =IF(1*G2<100,G2*7,G2*1)

Comment: The cells containing the numbers are formated as text and Excel considers them greater than 100 (any number).